# What is the best practice for assigning static IP addresses?

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, ip-address, static-ip

In my scenario, I would be assigning IP addresses to security cameras.

I am wondering if I should assign a static IP address from the device itself, or have a static entry on my DHCP server with their MAC addresses. I know both would work, but I was wondering if it is best practice to assign the IP from the devices, DHCP server, or both.

Comment: This comes down to whichever option works best for you to configure and maintain. If you prefer setting static mac reservations in the DHCP configuration or if you prefer configuring each IP camera. So it's a matter of preference, administration, and maintenance.

Comment: Its a matter of preference. The biggest advantage of using a DHCP reservation, is that you ensure that there are no IP Conflicts. But if you have a system and everyone else that maintains that network uses the same system, then static ip addresses will also work. One benefit of static ip addresses is that if the DHCP server goes wonky, it may stop access to the camera's and troubleshooting that its the DHCP server can be tricky. Your camera stops working, and it is then not the DHCP server that you usually think of at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

If your Router can handle DHCP Reservation, I find this to be the best way to handle small device Static IP setup. If the device changes you need only change the MAC address in the router and you are good to go. No setup in the device required.

This method also helps to ensure that other individuals will not set up conflicting IP addresses. IP setup is under the control of the person setting up the MAC address table.

Now not all Routers can do DHCP Reservation: My older Cisco RV325 CAN; my newer Cisco RV345 could not initially but now with later firmware updates CAN.

So you have to take your router into account, but my experience (Servers and Routers) is that DHCP reservation is better than setting up a device with Static IP.

While there is an element of personal preference of course, DHCP Reservation is a fairly normal business practice (used on all my Customer Servers) and works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it can be configuration preferences concerning central versus non-central:

If I want to have a central administration interface I usually go for DHCP setup with IP reservations.

If central administration doesn't matter I don't bother about reserving IPs on the DHCP server. But you need to make sure that static IPs and dynamic IPs have their separate ranges to avoid assigning the same IP to two devices.

Doing both is possible but it's twice the work I don't see any benefit to your particular use case.